# How to use chrome dev tools apis in puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to use chrome dev tool APIs in puppeteer is there a way to call chrome dev tools API using puppeteer ( Programmatically )

**Example:**

- Copy X-Path
- CSS overview ( Capture Overview )

Thank you.

Comment: No, these features are implemented in devtools front-end, not in the underlying protocol used by puppeteer. You can try finding an existing js library that implements the same or extract & adapt devtools code.